# How do I define a SWIG typemap for a reference to pointer?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a Publisher class written in C++ with the following two methods:

```
PublishField(char* name, double* address);
GetFieldReference(char* name, double*& address);
```

Python bindings for this class are being generated using SWIG.  In my swig .i file I have the following:

```
 %pointer_class(double*, ptrDouble);
```

This lets me publish a field that is defined in a Python variable:

```
value = ptrDouble()
value.assign(10.0)
PublishField("value", value.cast())
```

Trying to using the GetFieldReference method results in a TypeError however:

```
GetFieldReference("value", newValue)
```

I think I need to create a typemap for the double*& that returns a ptrDouble, but I am not quite sure what that would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution that I came up with.

Add a wrapper function to the swig.i file:

```
%inline %{
    double * GetReference(char* name, Publisher* publisher)
    {
         double* ptr = new double;
         publisher->GetFieldReference(name, ptr);
         return ptr;
    }
%}
```

Now from Python I can use the following:

```
value = ptrDouble.frompointer(GetFieldReference("value", publisher)
```

Answer (score 0):

This typemap should solve the problem -

```
// Typemaps for double *&
%typemap(in) double *& (double *ppDouble  = NULL) %{
$1 = &ppDouble  ;
%}

%typemap(argout) double *& {
*(double **)&jarg2 = *$1;
}

%typemap(javain) double *& "$javainput"
```

You may need to check if assigning jarg2 (in 'argout' typemap) with required double value is correct or jarg1 should be assigned rather.